# AWS IAM EC2 Access to Instance ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Trying to setup a user to only be able to access one type of instance and only be abled to stop and start the instance. But when I setup a policy for it the i just get an error saying not authorized:

```
 An error occurred fetching instance data: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Account ID was retrieved from security page.

For the sake of testing i have allowed all actions (ec2:*) and tried these policy's

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "ec2:*", 
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:instance/i-XXXXXXX"    
    }
  ]
}
```

with tag dev

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1411556016000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances"
      ],
      "Resource" : "*"
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/Environment": "dev"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124539/how-to-show-specific-ec2-instance-for-an-user), but to answer, you probably also need to give `DescribeInstances` permissions.

Comment: I did ask before that question, but either way it has answered my question.