# how to show specific ec2 instance for an user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I have some aws ec2 instances and would like to show ONLY one instance for partners.

I created IAM user for the partner. following is my policy I created.
But when partner logins to aws and see ec2 instance view, following message displayed and no instance is displayed.

> An error occurred fetching instance data: You are not authorized to
>   perform this operation.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Sid": "Stmt1373378552000",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:ap-northeast-1:123456789012:instance/i-12345678"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

(123456789012 is (dummy)my Account Id and i-12345678 is a instance I like to show)

I also tried to specify by tag name like following, but does not work..

```
"Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "node-B"
        }
      },
```

Does anyone know how to show specific ec2 instance for partners??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently supported.

Only selected Amazon EC2 API actions currently support resource-level permissions:

- **Describe** calls do not support resource-level permissions
- **Start/Stop/Terminate** (and others) are supported

The AWS Management Console is using a `DescribeInstances` call, which cannot be restricted to a specific resource. Hence, the error you received.

See also:

- [Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html)

Comment: To further clarify, the `DescribeInstances` action cannot be restricted by *any* `Condition`. Even if you set `"Resource": "*"`.